# ListPreference Array Entry Disable CheckBox Preference

Tags: android, listpreference

How do we disable a CheckBox preference according to an array selection in a ListPreference?

What I have is if Auto Mode or Manual Mode are selected I don't want a CheckBox that controls the Accelerometer Axis Inversion to be enabled. How can I do it in real time? Thanks for the tip.

Jason

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>

<string-array name="game_mode_text">
        <item>Auto Mode</item>
        <item>Manual Mode</item>
        <item>Accelerometer Mode</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="game_mode_values">
        <item>0</item>
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>  





 @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceTreeClick(PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen,
            final Preference preference) {
            ListPreference accelMode = (ListPreference) findPreference("ModeKey");
            CheckBoxPreference checkBoxPreference = (CheckBoxPreference)findPreference("invertAccelKey");
        if(preference.equals(accelMode)) {
            String value = preference.getSharedPreferences().getString("ModeKey", "0");

            if(value.equalsIgnoreCase("0") || value.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                checkBoxPreference.setEnabled(false);
            }else 
                checkBoxPreference.setEnabled(true);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to achieve that is to set `Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener` for the `ListPreference` and change state of the `CheckBoxPreference` according to selected value.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override

```
 @Override
 public boolean onPreferenceTreeClick(PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen, Preference preference) 
{
    //here you can disable  if Auto Mode is selected by 
     pref.setEnabled(false)

}
```

**EDIT1**

```
 public boolean onPreferenceTreeClick(PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen,
            final Preference preference) {

     if(preference.equals("MyListPreference")) {

          String value = preference.getSharedPreferences().getString("KEY", "Default value");
if(value.equalsIgnoreCase("Value")) {
    //Disable checkbox preference
}
        }
  }
```

**EDIT2**

```
@Override
    public boolean onPreferenceTreeClick(PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen,
            final Preference preference) {
ListPreference MyListPreference = (ListPreference) findPreference("MyListPreferenceKey");
        if(preference.equals(MyListPreference)) {

            String value = preference.getSharedPreferences().getString("KEY", "Default value");
            if(value.equalsIgnoreCase("Value")) {
                CheckBoxPreference checkBoxPreference = (CheckBoxPreference)findPreference("checkBoxPreferenceKey");
                checkBoxPreference.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the helpful replies the part were I'm stuck is checking which list preference entry is checked as list pref does not seem to have this method isChecked. Jason

Comment: getString is not valid for preference

Comment: Hi Dharmendra, this works but you have to select the list preference entry twice for the checkbox to be disabled and enabled I will edit my first post for you to see. The entry that disables it has to be clicked twice in order for the checkbox to be disabled and the entry that enables it has to clicked twice to enable it.